# High availability Server + NAS - TrueNas + Docker

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, nas, truenas

For some time now I have been toying with the idea of having my own server to be able to deploy my applications, web pages, etc.

My father has presented me with the idea that he wants to have a NAS to store files that he rarely uses, it would be enough if I could share the data with NFS or even SMB, since he is an Ubuntu user.

I had thought about setting up a "server" with TrueNas. Since we live in different locations, I would like to have a "replica" in his location.

I've been doing some research on how TrueNas Scale works with HA and the Cluster, and I'm not sure I understand if it would meet my needs. Of course, I'm open to other solutions, I just saw that one has a lot of community support and has a good reputation.

My use cases would be the following:

- Have two servers that can talk to each other, and synchronise at least certain datasets, could be a pool, a folder, etc.
- Have services like Jellyfin, or a basic http server deployed on both, so that if one fails (power or internet goes down), the other is able to continue running with the same data. If the failed server is up, it will be able to synchronise with the second one.
- All pointing to a single ip, as I would use DDNS to have a single point of entry, ideally the two servers would be connected via a VPN.

So, here I have several doubts.

- TrueNas Scale can deploy docker containers, but I'm not sure if it can ever have a DockerSwarm, which is what I had in mind to have high availability of the dockers.
- Even if the above point were possible, I'm not sure how the containers would handle the data. I mean, if I have for example NextCloud on serverA and serverB as docker containers, would both NextCloudA and NextCloudB point to the storage of only one of the servers, say, ServerA?
- I had thought about having the VPN on one of the servers, but I understand that it might be best to have it on an external raspberry pi so that I can manage both VPN and DDNS there? Here I would run into the problem that if the Raspberry network fails, everything will fail.

What advice or ideas can you give me? I don't expect you to tell me exactly how to do it, but maybe the tools/topology I'm putting forward here are completely wrong for these uses and there are others to achieve this that you can bow to.

Maybe this scheme can help a bit.

[diagram for the topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyA5k.png)

Comment: This isn't a bad question, it just isn't going to get the sort of response it needs on this site. This is a Question and Answer site. We do single, specific, practical questions that can be single, specific, and correct answers. This question needs more open and on-going discussion in order to fully explore the topics you're looking into. I recommend you find a forum to ask this in. It will be closed here for being too broad and/or opinion based because it simply doesn't fit here.